# Importing to phpmyadmin error

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import a WordPress database, but I'm getting this error:SQL query:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 2.8.0.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
-- 
-- Host: custsql-nf04.eigbox.net
-- Generation Time: May 16, 2014 at 08:07 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.32
-- PHP Version: 4.4.9
-- 
-- Database: `beyondth_datawp`
-- 
-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Table structure for table `blogtalkradio`
-- 
CREATE TABLE  `blogtalkradio` (

 `id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `email` VARCHAR( 150 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `id` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT =25DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT =25;

MySQL said: Documentation

#1046 - No database selected
```

I Exported the original database in smaller portions because it's too large for one file.  It looks like there's one custom process in the original database, but I don't know how to copy it to the new one.  Where in PHPmyadmin can I go to view the sql query code that was entered?

I'm importing this to a new/empty database.

Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting? That isn't included in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Error Says #1046 - No database selected , are you getting the same error ? , if yes then how are you importing this data,

if using phpmyadmin , then select the database and in that select import.

or if using command line ,make sure you are using the following format.

mysql  -u < user > -p < < the sql file >

Regards

Suyash